# How can i write better my jquery code?

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

i want better write my code. i am not pro coder. 
i want member choice my offer form check services, 
- service 1,2,3 same grup,
- service 7,8,9,10,11,12,13 another grup,
- and another single (4,5,6)

i not know how better and short write like this code. thank you so much.

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/elturko/v5rjE/

**HTML**

```
<input name="service[]" value="1" class="service_type" type="checkbox"> service 1<br />
<input name="service[]" value="2" class="service_type" type="checkbox"> service 2<br />
<input name="service[]" value="3" class="service_type" type="checkbox"> service 3<br />
<input name="service[]" value="4" class="service_type" type="checkbox"> service 4<br />
<input name="service[]" value="5" class="service_type" type="checkbox"> service 5<br />
<input name="service[]" value="6" class="service_type" type="checkbox"> service 6<br />
<input name="service[]" value="7" class="service_type" type="checkbox"> service 7<br />
<input name="service[]" value="8" class="service_type" type="checkbox"> service 8<br />
<input name="service[]" value="9" class="service_type" type="checkbox"> service 9<br />
<input name="service[]" value="10" class="service_type" type="checkbox"> service 10<br />
<input name="service[]" value="11" class="service_type" type="checkbox"> service 11<br />
<input name="service[]" value="12" class="service_type" type="checkbox"> service 12<br />
<input name="service[]" value="13" class="service_type" type="checkbox"> service 13<br /><br /><br />


<div id="service123">service1 or service2 or service3</div>
<div id="service4">service4</div>
<div id="service5">service5</div>
<div id="service6">service6</div>
<div id="others">other services(7-13)</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{ display:none;}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var checked = [];
$("input:checkbox[name=service[]]").live('click', function (){
    var $this = $(this), 
    h = $this.val();

    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        checked.push(parseInt(h));
        if(h<=3) $("#service123").show(); // 1,2,3 any one
        else if(h==4) $("#service4").show();
        else if(h==5) $("#service5").show();
        else if(h==6) $("#service6").show();
        else $("#others").show(); // 7-13 between
    }
    else{
        checked.splice(checked.indexOf(parseInt(h)),1);
        if((h <=3) && ($.inArray(1, checked) == -1 && $.inArray(2, checked) == -1 && $.inArray(3, checked) == -1)) $("#service123").hide();
        else if(h==4) $("#service4").hide();
        else if(h==5) $("#service5").hide();
        else if(h==6) $("#service6").hide();
        else if((7>= h <=13) && ($.inArray(7, checked) == -1 && $.inArray(8, checked) == -1 && $.inArray(9, checked) == -1 && $.inArray(10, checked) == -1 && $.inArray(11, checked) == -1 && $.inArray(12, checked) == -1 && $.inArray(13, checked) == -1)) $("#others").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather make markup more generic for all cases, like below

```
   <div class="service s1 s2 s3">service1 or service2 or service3</div>
   <div class="service s4">service4</div>
   <div class="service s5">service5</div>
   <div class="service s6">service6</div>
   <div class="service s7 s8 s9 s10 s11 s12 s13">other services(7-13)</div>
```

which will allow me to simplify the logic:

```
   $('.service').hide()

   $('input.service_type:checked').each(function() {
       $('.service.s'+this.value).show()
   })
```

your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v5rjE/2/

**UPDATE**: After reading your question one more time I can come up with another solution

Cosider adding some mapping to your code

```
   var serviceTypes = [0, 1,1,1,2,3,4]
    , services = ['#other', '#service123', '#service4', '#service5', '#service6']
```

now having checked value you can get id of service and use it to get selector

```
   services[serviceTypes[this.value]|0]
```

this will evaluate to something other than service, if exists in a mapping, or to `'#other'` in case mapping miss the value

so all the code again would be simple as:

```
   var serviceTypes = [0, 1,1,1,2,3,4]
    , services = ['#other', '#service123', '#service4', '#service5', '#service6']
    , all = services.join(',')             

   $(all).hide()      
   $('input.service_type:checked').each(function() {
       $(services[serviceTypes[this.value]|0]).show()
   })
```

Comment: thanks @vittore. i use your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5rjE/2/) method. i think more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
h = parseInt(h);
queryString = "#service"+h;
$(queryString).show();
```

It is easier to construct a string given whatever h is rather than have to handle each one individually. The concatenation in the second line is handled automatically because of automatic type detection. That will get rid of almost all your if's and else's.

Answer (score 0):

I like this. Maybe it will give you some ideas:

```
if ($this.is(':checked')) {
    checked.push(parseInt(h));
} else {
    checked.splice(checked.indexOf(parseInt(h)),1);
}

$("#service123, #service4, #service5, #service6, #others).hide();
for (var i=0; i < checked.length; ++i) {
    var id = "#service" + i;
    if (i <=3) id = "#service123";
    if (i > 6) id = "#others";
    $(id).show();
}
```

You could also change to use classes and give service123 class="service1 service2 service3" then do something similar for 7 and greater, so you wouldn't have to have the `if` statements. Just create ".service" + i and show it.

Note that either way, you end up hiding everything and showing some things more than once. No harm done.

Comment: checking easy but have about service some grup. i need this grup checking to control. for this mix doit every thing in my mind. long road wrote maybe have some short road for this i asked.

Comment: I'm having trouble with your English. Sorry. "Grup" is an unknown word to me. Otherwise I'm not understanding your comment. @vittore has the best answer so far.

Comment: Well, just study the answers you have so far and you will learn much about how to do such things.